# Vaadin Charts -ClassNotFoundException: com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent

Tags: java, tomcat, gwt, vaadin, ivy

I wrote a small demo web app which I can run on a tomcat server and that displays a vaadin chart.

When I restart the server and load the app for the first time, it works. As soon as I make a change to the code and the app should be automatically redeployed I get a *ClassNotFoundException: com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent* exception below. I recompiled the widgetset as chart requires this.

Before adding the Chart this was no problem so I assume something is missing for the chart component but it works when I restart the server which is puzzling me.

Could It be that I need to recompile the chart constantly also when not changing chart specific code and how would I need to adapt the ivy file to achieve this?

**Annotation:**

```
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = DerstandarduseranalyzerUI.class, widgetset = "com.example.derstandarduseranalyzer.widgetset.DerstandarduseranalyzerWidgetset")
```

**Widgetset gwt**

```
<inherits name="com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet" />
<inherits name="com.vaadin.addon.charts.Widgetset" />
<inherits name="com.vaadin.addon.timeline.gwt.TimelineWidgetSet" />
```

**ivy.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE ivy-module [
<!ENTITY vaadin.version "7.4.4">
 ]>
<ivy-module version="2.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">
<info organisation="com.example" module="v7proj" />
<configurations>

<conf name="default" />

<conf name="widgetset-compile" />

<conf name="nodeploy" />
</configurations>
<dependencies defaultconf="default" defaultconfmapping="default->default">
<dependency org="com.vaadin" name="vaadin-server" rev="&vaadin.version;" />
<dependency org="com.vaadin" name="vaadin-themes" rev="&vaadin.version;" />
<dependency org="com.vaadin" name="vaadin-push" rev="&vaadin.version;"     conf="default->default"/>
<dependency org="javax.servlet" name="javax.servlet-api" rev="3.0.1" conf="nodeploy->default" />
<dependency org="com.vaadin" name="vaadin-testbench-api" rev="latest.release" conf="nodeploy -> default" />
<dependency org="com.vaadin" name="vaadin-client-compiled"
rev="&vaadin.version;" />
<dependency org="com.vaadin" name="vaadin-client" rev="&vaadin.version;" conf="widgetset-compile->default" />
<dependency org="com.vaadin" name="vaadin-client-compiler"   rev="&vaadin.version;" conf="widgetset-compile->default" />
</dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

**ivysettings.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <ivysettings>
 <settings defaultResolver="default" />
 <resolvers>
 <chain name="default">

 <ibiblio name="public" m2compatible="true" />
 <ibiblio 
 name="vaadin-addons" 
 usepoms="true" 
 m2compatible="true" 
 root="http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons" />

 <ibiblio name="vaadin-addons" usepoms="true" m2compatible="true"
 root="http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons" />


 <ibiblio name="vaadin-snapshots" usepoms="true" m2compatible="true"
 root="https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots" />

 <dual name="custom-smartsprites">
 <filesystem name="smartsprites-ivy">
 <ivy pattern="${basedir}/ivymodule/[module]-ivy-[revision].xml" />
 </filesystem>
 <url name="smartsprites-artifact">
 <artifact
 pattern="http://dev.vaadin.com/svn/versions/6.8/build/smartsprites/lib/[artifact](-[revision]).[ext]" />
 </url>
 </dual>
 </chain>
 </resolvers>
 <modules>

 <module organisation="com.carrotsearch" name="smartsprites"
 revision="0.2.3-itmill" resolver="custom-smartsprites" />
 </modules>


 </ivysettings>
```

**Error**

> Apr 22, 2015 11:31:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   reload INFO: Reloading Context with name [/derStandardUserAnalyzer]
>   has started Apr 22, 2015 11:31:54 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase
>   checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks SEVERE: The web application
>   [/derStandardUserAnalyzer] created a ThreadLocal with key of type
>   [com.google.gson.Gson$1] (value [com.google.gson.Gson$1@e7f068c]) and
>   a value of type [java.util.HashMap] (value [{}]) but failed to remove
>   it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be
>   renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak. Apr 22,
>   2015 11:31:54 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars INFO:
>   At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable
>   debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were
>   scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during
>   scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time. Apr 22,
>   2015 11:31:54 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager
>   startInternal SEVERE: Exception loading sessions from persistent
>   storage java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/vaadin/ui/AbstractComponent at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2450)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:852)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1262)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1145)
>   at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.CustomObjectInputStream.resolveClass(CustomObjectInputStream.java:74)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClass(Unknown Source) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.skipCustomData(Unknown Source) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.doReadObject(StandardSession.java:1634)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObjectData(StandardSession.java:1099)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:261)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:180)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.startInternal(StandardManager.java:460)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5238)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3821)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:292)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.backgroundProcess(StandardContext.java:5576)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1377)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1381)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1381)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1349)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1293)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1145)

Comment: Only one widgetset compilation is needed, you don't need to do that during development (unless you develop the addon itself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens to me from time to time, too. Is not a Vaadin-related problem but an issue with the container. Basically it's not updating. Usually a reboot of the machine (it may be hanging somewhere) helps; a fast alternative is to do "Project > Clear" and on the server you are using for the Run / debug (Servers tab) "right click > Clear".
It's a bit annoying to do every time but worked for me.

Comment: Thanks - I will try that at home though I don't really see that as a solution if I need to do that everytime because the restart of the tomcat which resolves it is what I am doing already. I also tried clearing the Server and Project but I always needed to restart it.

Comment: Oh wait you cannot push runtime another version of a class! Of course you have to restart the server: when the JVM starts, it puts a sort of "cache" version of the .class and cannot be "hot" modified or things like "instanceof" would break. That's the only bad side of working with a webapp container with java ;-)

Comment: Thanks! But why did it work when just working on the UI/the core of the app and breaks since adding the chart component?

Comment: Now, that's an interesting question. Probably in simple cases the class loader with Vaadin is able to do this hot swapping, while with the addition of an addon maybe not.

Anyway if you are interested in hot swapping you can look at HotSwap JVM tool (free) or jrebel (commercial)